# Java iterable: why is iterator for one object iterates over data from another?

Tags: java, iterable

This is the first time I am working with Java `Iterable`'s and I ran into an issue that (i) is driving me mad and (ii) shows how little I understand!

I have the following class:

```
public class DocumentList implements Iterable<Document> {

private static ArrayList<Document> docs = null;
// other vars...

public DocumentList(InputStream in) {

    // load list from in

}

// other methods...

public Iterator<Document> iterator() {
    return new DocSetIterator();
}

private class DocSetIterator implements Iterator<Document> {
    private int ix = 0;

    public DocSetIterator() {
        ix = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return ix < nDocs;
    }

    public Document next() {
        if(this.hasNext()) {
            Document current = docs.get(ix++);
            return current;
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

}
```

where `Document` is another class. Then I have the following:

```
DocumentList dList1 = new DocumentList(in1);
DocumentList dList2 = new DocumentList(in2);

Iterator<Document> it = dList2.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Document d2 = it.next(); 
    // ...          
}
```

I am expecting `d2` to be one of the elements of `dList2` but instead I am seeing contents of an element of `dList1`! What's going on here?

Thx

Comment: What are `in1` and `in2`? Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Why is `docs` `static`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `static` in your declaration of `docs` (that restricts the class to one, and only one, `List` for all instances of `DocumentList`).

```
private ArrayList<Document> docs = null; // <-- not static.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of docs `ArrayList` is static.  `private static ArrayList<Document> docs = null`; Thus this ArrayList is the same for every instance of `DocumentList`